# Trying to pass a session from a Model Save into a view

Tags: python, django, session, request, save

I have some custom validation on one of my models, and I generate errors based on which validation failed. I want to pass these errors to my view.

```
class TimeSheet(models.Model):

    O = "Open"
    S = "Submitted"
    A = "Approved"
    R = "Needs review"

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (O, "Open"),
    (S, "Submitted"),
    (A, "Approved"),
    (R, "Needs Reviewing"),
    )

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 50, default="Open", choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    submitted_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    approved_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tande:timesheet', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ok_to_continue = True
        start_date = self.start_date
        end_date = self.end_date

        if end_date < start_date:
            error = "ERROR: Start date must be before end date"
            ok_to_continue = False

        # make sure both dates are in the same month
        if start_date.month != end_date.month:
            error = "ERROR: Start and end dates must be in the same month"
            ok_to_continue = False

        # VALIDATION
        if ok_to_continue:
            super(TimeSheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print error
            self.request.session['error_from_save'] = error
```

However, this raises the error:

> AttributeError: 'TimeSheet' object has no attribute 'request'

Why is `self.request.session` not working? Is there another way to pass this back to my view?

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the model's `save()` method is not the preferred way to do validation. You should either provide a `validators` attribute to each field in your model and provide them with [custom-written validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/), or do the validation in the (Model)Form where you [override the `clean_fieldname` methods of your form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform).

The reason you can't pass things back to the view from the model's save method is that the save method may not always be called from a view. It may be called from the shell, for example. So there wouldn't always be a view or a session to return things to.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I'll try that. What's the problem with overriding the model save? Just because I am saving it as an object at the moment because I couldn't get forms to work with ajax (validation problems) and return data to the view.

Comment: Validation should run before `save`. With your custom check `ok_to_continue = True` you are effectively re-enventing the Django process that is already implemented via `clean`, `clean_*` and the validators. These might also run in circumstances where `save` is not called.